# Angular ng repeat filter inside ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been trying to make a list of geozones, with a select of taxes each (not all taxes apply to all geozones).

So I did a ng-repeat for the geozones, and inside each of them a ng-repeat with all taxes. Problem is I don't know how to send the id of the geozone being filtered at the moment. This is the code right now:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="tax in taxClasses | filter: filterTax" value="{{ '{{ tax.id }}' }}">{{ '{{ tax.name }}' }}</md-option>
```

and the JS:

```
$scope.filterTax = function(tax, n){

        angular.forEach(tax.geoZone , function(geo){
           if(geo === $scope.prices[n].geozoneId){
               return true;
           } 
        });
        return false;
    };
```

Need n to be the index of the geozone, or something of the sort. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is not that far off, but using `filter:` is not even necessary, as the pipe `|` is already a `filter` command:

```
ng-repeat="<var> in <array> | <filterFunction>:<...arguments>"
```

Thus you can create a filter (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter for details on that)

```
ng-repeat="tax in taxClasses | filterTax: <geozoneIndex>"
```

The value form the collection will be passed as the *first argument* of your `filterTax` function. Any further argument is passed separated by a colon `:`.

When you use this, you have to propagate a filter method like this:

```
app.module(...).filter('filterTax', function(/* injected services */) {
  return function (/* arguments */ input, geozoneIndex) {
    // function body
  }
});
```

Alternatively use a filter function from your scope:

```
// template
ng-repeat="tax in filterTaxes(taxClasses, <geozoneIndex>)"

// script
$scope.filterTaxes = function(taxClasses, geozoneIndex) {
  // do the whole filtering, but return an array of matches
  return taxClasses.filter(function(taxClass) {
    return /* in or out code */;
  });
};
```

This means your `geozoneIndex` may be either a fixed value or being pulled from a variable, that's available in that scope.

Just be aware that your `filterTax` function will be called **a lot**, so if your page is getting slow you might want to consider optimizing that filtering.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But I'm getting an Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:filterTaxFilterProvider<-filterTaxFilter. I tried every combination of arguments in the HTML and the JS but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Updated my answer. The filters I proposed at first need to be known in your module, but there's an maybe more easy alternative, which I provided as well.